# jQuery binding and unbinding

Tags: jquery, bind, attr

i have the following problem. On my page i have for example 5 elements with name attribute. And on document ready i bind a function on their click event using this selector:

```
   $('span[name="test"]').bind('click',function(){ // code });
```

That all works fine, but on the bottom of my page, i have a button which loads more elements on my page with the same name attribute. Normally their click event is not binded. Then i do the following:

```
   $('span[name="test"]').unbind('click');
   $('span[name="test"]').bind('click',function(){ // code });
```

All of this works fine, but my question is this: Is there a way to bind the remaining elements without unbinding already binded ones??

Comment: Yes; it's called [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be this i think, then you don't need to worry if the element was there or not before.

```
$(document).on('click','span[name="test"]',function(){ // code });
```

jQuery [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was added on v.1.7, and this answer uses [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Your answer is better than mine because it works with the code provided.  I prefer to not attach all event listeners to the document, but rather the lowest level parent which will 'house' the changing elements.

Comment: @carter, we have basically the same answer. I just play safe card using `document`, but using a parent that was present at page load is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#container').on('click', 'span[name="test"]', function(){});
```